# How to redirect www and non www request to https non www version of my website in tomcat 8 at ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, tomcat8, amazon-elb

I am using EC2 Instance for my web application. I bought a new SSL and installed it at AWS classic load balancer and my SSL is working fine. But for an SEO point of view, I want to redirect all the requests from www and non-www and HTTP www and HTTP non-www request to https non-www version. I am running my application in tomcat 8 version. I don't have any apache or any other server. I read many articles they mentioned that by doing .htaccess file but I hope its doesn't work in tomcat8.

I create a file in the WEB-INF folder called rewrite.config. and past this code. it's working somehow but not all the above possible case.

```
# bounce all requests coming in on HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this URL forwarding in your DNS provider. I hope it is pretty straight forward check it your DNS provider.